# How to stop loop when creating an employee database?

Tags: python, list, search, return, edit

I'm stuck and I'm not sure what part of class I've missed... How can I get my script to end a loop once the user enters 'done'?  I still have more functions to add so a search by SSN can be done and return formatted results.  I feel so lost!

```
counter = len(employee_list)

#view all employees, enter employees, Search by SSN. Format as directed.
employee_list = []
for i in range(10):
    print('Please enter information for employee ' + str(i + 1) + ':')
    name = input('Enter employee first and last name, if finished type done:')
    ssn = input('Enter SSN: ')
    phone = input('Enter phone number: ')
    email = input('Enter email: ')
    salary = input('Enter salary: ')
employee_list.append([name,ssn,phone,email,salary])
index = int(input('Which action would you like to take next? Type "VIEW ALL", "SEARCH", OR 
"EXIT"'))
```

Comment: `if name == 'done': break`

Comment: i must be doing something wrong, when i enter that it doesn't break

Comment: the break doesn't discontinue the entry, it continues in the string.

Comment: I did it!  it needed to be at the end of that portion of user input!  not at the end of the complete action!

Comment: Indeed…that's where it needs to be (and the `employee_list.append()` needs to be part of the `for` loop)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#view all employees, enter employees, Search by SSN. Format as directed.
employee_list = []
for i in range(10):
    print('Please enter information for employee ' + str(i + 1) + ':')
    name = input('Enter employee first and last name, if finished type done:')
    if name == "done":
        break
    ssn = input('Enter SSN: ')
    if ssn == "done":
        break
    phone = input('Enter phone number: ')
    if phone == "done":
        break
    email = input('Enter email: ')
    if email == "done":
        break
    salary = input('Enter salary: ')
    if salary == "done":
        break
    employee_list.append([name,ssn,phone,email,salary])

index = int(input('Which action would you like to take next? Type "VIEW ALL", "SEARCH", OR "EXIT"'))
```